# Ubuntu Software apps cannot access non-system disks

Tags: 18.04, permissions, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 x64 installed on an internal SSD. The PC also has internal and external HDDs.

The problem is that any application that has been installed from Ubuntu Software doesn't have access to those HDDs.

E.g., I cannot save any file from Opera to them, and Inkscape cannot open/save the files from/to those HDDs.

I've tried changing the apps' permissions in Ubuntu Software itself but they are never saved.

How can I overcome such issues?

Comment: 1.) Have you mounted the extra drives? if so where? 2.) What is the output when you try to save a file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the root of the problem: it appeared to be **snap**-packages issue. I've managed to make some apps to work with non-system disks by connecting **removable-media** plug (but only those apps which have it):

sudo snap connect PACKAGE_NAME:removable-media